# Client Script Not Running When Using Custom Role

Tags: netsuite

I have this client script when I test with administrator it works fine. But when I use a custom role its not working. I have checked that custom role has access to all the records in this script. And the script audience is set to all role and released status.

I have added log to check what went wrong and seem like the custom role user can load the script cos I can see the first 2 log but just cannot get into this if statement. Any clue why ??

````
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 *@NModuleScope Public
*/
define(["N/currentRecord", "N/search", "N/log"], function (currentrecord, search, log) {

    function fieldChanged(context) {

        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
        var sublistId = context.sublistId;
        var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;
        var sublistline = context.line
        log.debug('sublistId:',sublistId); 
        log.debug('sublistFieldName:',sublistFieldName);
      
        if (sublistId == 'item' && sublistFieldName == 'item') {
            log.debug('sublistId:',sublistId);
            log.debug('sublistFieldName:',sublistFieldName);
            log.debug('line:',sublistline);
```
`
````

Comment: There is no NetSuite permission required between the second log and the `if` block.  The one thing that could stop the script progressing into the `if` block is the `if` condition.  Make sure this evaluates to `true` in your tests - IE: that the logs for `sublistId` and `sublistFieldName` both say 'item'.  If that doesn't help, try changing your `if` block to `if (true) { ... }`.

Comment: A couple of notes. This script looks like copy/paste without much understanding. 
client scripts don't generally need to import `N/currentRecord` since the context provides it. Your very first assignment overwrites the import. For dealing with items you almost always want to use the `postSourcing` event if you want to react on an item change.

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! I manage to resolve the issues , its due to conflict field change action in workflow. Once I inactive it works. But I still wonder why it works for administrator and not for custom role users.